# Laravel How to pass post data from one post method to another post method within the same controller?

Tags: laravel, post, methods

Suppose I have a search form which submit the search parameters to a post method with ajax, on that method I have returned the result in a view. Now on that view I have an option for user to select the range of record for printing in excel, so for this once again I need to submit the search parameters along with print settings to one another post method, on that method I need to search again for search parameters, and also limit the search for selected print ranges. So for this I need the same code block, but for avoiding that is it possible to call the search post method from within the print post method? If possible How can I do that? Or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are passing some data from client to server using POST, it will be available in every method. You don't have to pass it from one to another.

In your case, it is better to move your business logic to a repository. You can create a new folder called `repositories`, under `app` directory. Then create a new repository class say `SearchRepository`, something like below

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchRepository {
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request      = $request;
    }
    /**
    * Search details
    * 
    * @return array
    */
    public function getDetails() {
        $q = $this->request->get('q');
        $limit = $this->request->get('limit');

        // Do the search operation with parameters recieved

        return $result;
    }
}
```

You can use the above repository in any controller using dependency injection like below. This way, you don't need to repeat any of your business logic with in controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\SearchRepository

class SearchController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(SearchRepository $search) {
        $this->search       = $search;
    }

    public function searchAction() {
        $result = $this->search->getDetails();

        // return to view or whatever
    }

    public function printAction() {
        $result = $this->search->getDetails();

        // print excel code or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: What is `$helper` inside constructor?

Comment: It is typo. It should be `$search`

Comment: Can I use from `$request->all()` instead of `Input::all()` in repositories?

Comment: But with calling `$this->search->getDetails()` it highlight the statement as red and says that `Required parameter $request missing`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103050/discussion-between-nauphal-and-jones).

Comment: Following best practices, how should I call an external API from the Repository class? I mean, can I directly call the Http facade `Http::get('url')` from the `getDetails()` method, or should I create a separate class for that, like a Model, and call it from the method?